# Sorting html table columns client side without third party other than jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, jqgrid

I fetch data via a jQuery ajax call to a web api service.  I do not want to be sending up request to have the server side do the Order By asc / desc per column so what I want to do is **CLIENT SIDE  HTML Table sorting**

I have been using jQuery and Javascript throughout the project, but I would really prefer to NOT use 3rd party tools like jqgrid or datatable.net

What are my options?

I have the data in Javascript before it is getting spit out into html table rows so seems like an option to have a click event which sorts the data in the .each loop

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
function writeResponses(allData) {

var strResult = "<table id='headerTable' class='table'><thead id='headers'><th>ID</th><th>Location</th><th>Comment</th><th>Additional Information</th><th>Date Reported</th><th>TC Key</th>";
strResult += "<th>Loc Acct Num</th><th>TC Date</th><th>WorkedID</th><th>TC Type</th><th>Corrected TC Type</th></thead>";
$.each(allData, function (index, issues) {

    strResult += "<tr><td>" + issues.DOCCCOIssuesId + "</td><td> " + issues.Location + "</td><td>" + issues.Comment + "</td>";
    strResult += "<td>" + issues.AdditionalInformation + "</td><td>" + issues.DateReported + "</td><td>" + issues.TCKey + "</td>";
    strResult += "<td>" + issues.LocAcctNum + "</td><td>" + issues.TCDate + "</td><td>" + issues.WorkedByNTID + "</td>";
    strResult += "<td>"+issues.TCType+"</td><td>"+issues.CorrectedTCType+"</td></tr>";
});
strResult += "</table>";
$("#divResult").html(strResult);

}
```

**html table generated**

```
<table id="headerTable" class="table">
<thead id="headers">
<tr>
    <th>ID</th><th>Location</th><th>Comment</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>CCO</td>
        <td>Compliment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>afafd</td>
        <td>oafaf</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Since you have all of the data, can't you just `sort()` it first and then iterate over it to create the table?

Comment: sort data, replace rows. Also there are some handy sorting plugins that are very light weight and can save you some time

Comment: if you don't want 3rd party, then you have to go 1st party, so get busy banging out code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do your initial sort on the data as you receive it. allData appears to be an array so you can do:

```
allData.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.DOCCCOIssuesId < b.DOCCCOIssuesId ) return -1;
    if(a.DOCCCOIssuesId > b.DOCCCOIssuesId ) return 1;
    // other sort keys?
    return 0;
});
```

If you want to have clickable sort columns the example below may help:

```
jQuery("table.stats").each(function() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var tbl = $(this);
    $('th', this).click(function() {
        var clickRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        var body = $(this).closest('tbody').get(0);
        var col = $(this).index();
        var sortKeys = $(body).find('tr').not(clickRow).map(function(idx, row) {
            return {
                row: row,
                key: $('td', row).eq(col).text() // you can do all sorts of things besides simple text values. cache the key for efficiency
            };
        }).get();
        sortKeys.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.key > b.key ? 1 : a.key < b.key ? -1 : 0; 
        });
        for (var i = sortKeys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            body.appendChild(sortKeys[i].row);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is pretty nice.   I just also ran across http://tablesorter.com/docs/ which took me like 1 minute to implement and it works great.   I definitely didn't want jqgrid and datatables.net ,  and I do prefer to hand code most of the time, but in a rush this table sorter plugin is so easy  ,  thx for your stuff that will be handy as well